# NSFileProtectionKey getting removed after iOS 8 OTA upgrade?

Tags: ios, ios8

On an app, after iOS 8 OTA upgrade from iOS 7, we noticed that attributesOfItemAtPath showed a different value for a particular file as NSFileProtectionKey is removed by upgrade process.

Anyone else see this?  What's the scope of this change?

Comment: Is this a file or directory that also has the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.   How will that impact it?

Answer (score 0):

When the App Store downloads an update, it is installed into a new directory before moving over files from a previous installation. [Files inside these application directories are migrated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW16):

`Documents`

`Library`

Files in other locations may or may not be migrated. Your application should not rely on other files being present after an upgrade.
When iOS detects a low disk space condition it chooses which files to purge. Files in `NSCachesDirectory` and `NSTemporaryDirectory()` can be purged. Files or directories with the "do not back up" attribute (`NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey`/`kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey`) will not be purged, and your application is responsible for cleaning them up. [From the iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html):

> Use the "do not back up" attribute for specifying files that should remain on device, even in low storage situations. Use this attribute with data that can be recreated but needs to persist even in low storage situations for proper functioning of your app or because customers expect it to be available during offline use. This attribute works on marked files regardless of what directory they are in, including the Documents directory. These files will not be purged and will not be included in the user's iCloud or iTunes backup. Because these files do use on-device storage space, your app is responsible for monitoring and purging these files periodically.

There is an important note about this attribute in NSURL.h:

> true if resource should be excluded from backups, false otherwise (Read-write, value type boolean NSNumber). This property is only useful for excluding cache and other application support files which are not needed in a backup. Some operations commonly made to user documents will cause this property to be reset to false and so this property should not be used on user documents.

When this attribute is used in combination with `NSFileProtectionKey`, undefined behavior can result. The backup attribute is read and written by one subsystem, while the file protection key is used by another. During an application upgrade or restore, a file may be migrated or restored without property preserving the file protection value. Additionally, adding the data protection attribute to a file will replace the old file with the protected one. This is transparent to your application, but can have the side effect of having an upgrade or restore put the unprotected version in place. This is one of the many reasons it's recommended to set this attribute whenever the file is written to by your application.

Comment: I did some tests and noticed that under low storage conditions, files with NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey do not get purged.

Comment: @Blaze, you are correct, I had the logic flipped. At the time I wrote this originally the relevant documentation was not available. Answer updated.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe those citations clarify anything about why `NSFileProtectionKey` gets reset. The second citation talks about some _writes_ to _user documents_ causing the DoNotBackup flag to be reset. In my case, however, `NSFileProtectionKey` is reset for a file under `Library/Application Support`, a location explicitly mentioned as fine by the docs.

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov Technote 2285 covers that for the app update use case, which for this discussion is the same. `Library/` inside the application sandbox is migrated the same as `Documents/` with the exception of the caches subdirectory.

Comment: @quellish Yes, Library is migrated just like Documents, but nothing says that the attributes will be reset during that migration. (The opposite would make sense: moving the file wouldn't change any metadata. iOS must be actively resetting the protection attribute.)

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov Apple never *explicitly* documents what happens to apps when an OTA OS update happens. You can, however, disassemble the daemons that are involved in the process and come to your own conclusions or attempt to get clarification from Developer Technical Services.

Comment: @quellish My point exactly; no documentation applies to this case, the observed behavior is entirely undocumented. In my specific case, though, it makes sense in light of a likely cause (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36021960/58146), so there's no need for DTS.

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov Contact DTS. Their response will have additional insights (and be under NDA) as this was a known issue with iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any official answer or documentation that applies.

Anecdotally, in my case, files under `Library/Application Support` have been set to `NSFileProtectionComplete` upon app upgrade, on iOS 9 and 8.

This *seeems* to be caused by Data Protection being set to Complete on the App ID on the Apple's servers, which in turn *seems* to have been automatically updated by Xcode when it regenerated provisioning profiles after certificate renewal (despite Data Protection capability being Off in the local Xcode project).

This actually makes sense. iOS plays it safe and takes care of upgrading the data protection on all files after you enable data protection entitlement for a new release.

What does not make sense is when someone else (ahem Xcode ahem) decides to add that entitlement for you.

Things to add to a release checklist:

- recheck the settings of your App ID on the certificates portal (paying special attention to the data protection setting)